# Samba drives on Ubuntu lost priviledges, directories now defunct, what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, samba

I defined two Samba network drives to /mnt on a server. Our network uses LDAP authentication.

For some reason it seems like at some point the priviledges were lost. Now /mnt looks like

```
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?                ? foo
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?                ? bar
```

And I can't do anything to those directories. Deleting by name or inode doesn't work ("permission denied" even for root) so what can I do? Root doesn't seem to have any rights to those directories.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you don't have execute permissions on a folder, but you have read permissions. I was able to reproduce the error this way:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/tt
$ ls -l | grep test
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user   4096 2011-12-27 17:05 test
$ chmod -x test
$ ls -l test
ls: cannot access test/tt: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? tt
```

So, the problem should be fixed after you grant the user the `x` permission in addition to `r`.

Comment: Neither chmod nor chown works on that file, unfortunately.